# CSS animations cycle doesn't work as it should

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, css-animations, keyframe

I have created two classes for two animations that pressing a button should turn fullscreen on and off using one animation first and another one after a second press of the button.

CSS
Animate enable fullscreen, animatereverse disable it

```
    #mv {
        width: 100%;
        height: 57%;
    }

    .animate {
        animation: fullscreen 0.5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes fullscreen {
        from {
            height: 57%;
        }

        to {
            height: 100%;
        }
    }


    .animatereverse {
        animation: fullscreenreverse 0.5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes fullscreenreverse {
        from {
            height: 100%;
        }

        to {
            height: 57%;
        }
    }
```

TS/JS
I used a flag to make the function know if the interface is in fullscreen or not

```
      var fullscreen = false;
      //console.log(" fullscreen now false ");
        document.getElementById('fllbtn').addEventListener("click", function () {          
          if(fullscreen == false){     
            //console.log(" fullscreen is false ");
            fullscreen = true;
            //console.log(" fullscreen now true ");
            document.getElementById("mv").classList.toggle("animate");
          }else{
            //console.log(" fullscreen is true ");
            fullscreen = false;
            //console.log(" fullscreen now false ");
            document.getElementById("mv").classList.toggle("animatereverse");
          }
        })
```

The problem is as follows:

**BEGIN**
*non-fullscreen interface
*I press fullscreen button
*animation works, interface becomes fullscreen
*I press fullscreen button
*animation works, interface returns to initial non-fullscreen state
*I press fullscreen button
*animation does not work, does not go fullscreen
*I press the fullscreen button
*animation does not work, does not go to fullscreen
**END**

Think of it as a loop, it basically runs twice, jumps twice and repeats like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way, I simply use a transition:

CSS

```
#mv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 57%;
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

#mv.fullscreen {
    height: 100%;
}
```

TS/JS

```
  document.getElementById('fllbtn').addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("mv").classList.toggle("fullscreen");
  })
```

Comment: Please *never* post pictures of code if at all avoidable, it makes life exponentially more difficult for both others searching for answers and for the OP who has to manually type out your code just to test if it works.

Comment: You're right! I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

`toggle('classname')` will add the class when it's not present, or remove it when it *is* present.
This means that:

1. first fullscreen is click
2. first toggle runs; `.animate` class is added to the `#mv`
3. second fullscreen click
4. 2nd time the function runs, `.animatereverse` is added to the `#mv`
5. `#mv` now has both classes `.animate` AND `.animatereverse`
6. 3th click on full screen
7. function runs again, toggle is triggered for `.animate.`  this will remove the `.animate` class from `#mv`
   1.`#mv` now only has `.animatereverse` you didn't see any animation because no new animation was applied

Instead of using toggle, you could try to add and remove the classes explicitly.

```js
var fullscreen = false;

document.getElementById('fllbtn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  fullscreen = !fullscreen;
  if (fullscreen) {
    document.getElementById("mv").classList.remove("animatereverse");
    document.getElementById("mv").classList.add("animate");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mv").classList.add("animatereverse");
    document.getElementById("mv").classList.remove("animate");
  }

})
```

```css
#mv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 57%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: salmon;
}

.animate {
  animation: fullscreen 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fullscreen {
  from {
    height: 57%;
  }
  to {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.animatereverse {
  animation: fullscreenreverse 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fullscreenreverse {
  from {
    height: 100%;
  }
  to {
    height: 57%;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button id="fllbtn">fullscreen</button>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="mv">
    i'm mv
  </div>
</div>
```